# BackgroundWorker's progress bar is not working

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

The BackgroundWorker's progressbar is not updated while doing some tasks. What I would like to reach is progressbar moving while iterating through each file in DirectoryInfo. Suppose we have 20 files of ".sql" while first file completed it should be 5%, 10% and etc.
Here is my code.

```
private void CSV_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {         
            try
            {
                btnExtract.IsEnabled = false;
                workerextract.RunWorkerAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void workerextract_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {

                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(txtQueryfolder.Text);
                files = di.GetFiles("*.sql").Count();
                currentfile = 0;

                foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.sql"))
                {
                    // Open the text file using a stream reader.
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fi.FullName))
                    {
                        // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                        string line = sr.ReadToEnd();

                        //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(line);
                        ExtractToCSV(line, System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name));
                        currentfile++;
                    }
                    int percentage = (currentfile + 1) * 100 / files;
                    workerextract.ReportProgress(percentage);
                }

            });

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void workerextract_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBarExtract.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void workerextract_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnExtract.IsEnabled = true;
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("CSV Data extraction finished!");
    }
```

I found that

> private void workerextract_ProgressChanged(object sender,
>   System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)

is called once at the end when 100%.
Also,

> private void workerextract_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,
>   RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)

never called as I do not see Message Box at the end.

So, I think I am doing something wrong here, could you please direct me on right way?

Comment: Why would it be called more than once? You're only reporting progress once - at the end. You're not reporting progress at all in your loop.

Comment: I have modified my code, even inside loop it is called only once.

Comment: You go to all of the effort of creating a background worker - and then ask the `Dispatcher` to move the bulk of your code *back* onto the UI thread. Why would you do that?

Comment: Otherwise it is causing "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Comment: So *stop* accessing UI objects from your background worker code. Or if you "have" to access UI objects, just wrap *those lines* with `Dispatcher.Invoke`, not the *whole* loop.

Comment: Why are you spawning a background worker just to run it on the UI thread??? `this.Dispatcher.Invoke`.  That defeats the whole purpose

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Should I wrap only                     DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(txtQueryfolder.Text);  with Dispatcher.Invoke ?

Comment: @MickyD I am getting error  "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." if I do not wrap with Dispatcher.Invoke

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I understood my mistake and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Using `this.Dispatcher.Invoke` in the `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` event you are executing the whole operation in the UI thread; which is what `BackgroundWorker` born to avoid to do.

Also, you get an error unwrapping your code from the dispatcher because you are accessing an UI object, which is `txtQueryfolder`.

Just use:

```
private void workerextract_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string queryFolder = e.Argument.ToString();
    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(queryFolder);
        files = di.GetFiles("*.sql").Count();
        currentfile = 0;

        foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.sql"))
        {
            // Open the text file using a stream reader.
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fi.FullName))
            {
                // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                string line = sr.ReadToEnd();

                //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(line);

                // ExtractToCSV shouldn't access to a UI object.
                ExtractToCSV(line, System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name));
                currentfile++;
            }
            int percentage = (currentfile + 1) * 100 / files;
            workerextract.ReportProgress(percentage);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Don't use MessageBox in a thread different from the UI one. Just set the result (e.Result) and get that in the RunWorkerCompleted event.
        // System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

When you call the `RunWorkerAsync` method just add the parameter like below:

```
workerextrac.RunWorkerAsync(txtQueryfolder.Text);
```

Comment: The line  ExtractToCSV(line, System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name)); gives an error of "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Comment: You should post the code of the `ExtractToCSV` function in order to get helped or just try to comment the content of that function and see if it works correctly; just debug it :)

Comment: Yes it works if I comment the ExtractToCSV, I just wrapped with Dispatcher.Invoke that part and it seems everything is fine, thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov, glad to help. I'm happy that you figured it out but, again, this shouldn't be the right solution AFAIK. Iterating and executing the `ExtractToCSV` function is the time-spend part of the method. All of the part should be executed in the background thread. Howerver, just a tip :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in wrapping whole DoWork inside Dispatcher.Invoke.
I need to wrap only those code where it is interacting with UI.
So I changed the code appropriately and it works.

```
 private void workerextract_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    di = new DirectoryInfo(txtQueryfolder.Text);
                });
                    files = di.GetFiles("*.sql").Count();
                    currentfile = 0;

                foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.sql"))
                {
                    // Open the text file using a stream reader.
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fi.FullName))
                    {
                        // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                        string line = sr.ReadToEnd();

                        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                        //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(line);
                        ExtractToCSV(line, System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name));
                        });

                        currentfile++;
                    }
                    int percentage = (currentfile + 1) * 100 / files;
                    workerextract.ReportProgress(percentage);
                }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Thanks to all for showing the direction.

Comment: This is not the right approach, even if it's working. Please take a look at my updated answer. Also, with is the code of `ExtractToCSV`? Why should it access to an UI object?

Comment: @OmarMuscatello See my comment below your answer